# Custom form with range sliders breaks and I don't know why

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, range

I'm creating a custom form with two sliders (actually three, because I converted two sliders to a range slider.
I'm using `input type="range"`.

With JS I've added some restrictions to the custom range slider.

- The input value representing the max value can't be less than the min value
- When the min value is larger than the max value, the max value gets reset to a value 100 larger than the min value

The starting value for min and max is 0 and 100.
Now for some reason, the custom range slider breaks when you adjust the min value to more than 100 and then change it back to less then 100.
*Update: or as soon as the min value is set to 8 or higher... -_-*
The max value set to (min value + 100) while this should only happen when max is less than min (max < min) like I said above.

I can't figure out why this happens and how to solve this.

```js
function equalizeMin(value) {
  let maxVal = document.getElementById('maxText').value;
  
  if(value > maxVal) {
    document.getElementById('maxText').value = Number(value) + 100;
    document.getElementById('maxRange').value = Number(value) + 100;
  }
  
  document.getElementById('minText').value = value;
  document.getElementById('minRange').value = value;
  
  setAvg();
}

function equalizeMax(value) {
  let minVal = document.getElementById('minText').value;
  if(value >= minVal) {
    document.getElementById('maxText').value = value;
    document.getElementById('maxRange').value = value;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('maxText').value = minVal;
    document.getElementById('maxRange').value = minVal;
  }
  setAvg();
}

function equalizeAvg(value) {
  document.getElementById('avgText').value = value;
  document.getElementById('avgRange').value = value;
}

function setAvg() {
  let _minVal = document.getElementById('minText').value;
  let _maxVal = document.getElementById('maxText').value;
  let avgVal = Number(_minVal) + Math.round((_maxVal - _minVal) / 2);
  
  document.getElementById('avgText').min = _minVal;
  document.getElementById('avgRange').min = _minVal;
  
  document.getElementById('avgText').max = _maxVal;
  document.getElementById('avgRange').max = _maxVal;
  
  document.getElementById('avgText').value = avgVal;
  document.getElementById('avgRange').value = avgVal;
}

window.onload = setAvg();  
//
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}
form span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(50% - 2px);
}
form span label {
  display: block;
}
form span input[type="number"] {
  width: 100%;
}
form .range, form .average {
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  width: 100%;
}
form .range input[type="range"], form .average input[type="range"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: silver;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: block;
  height: 8px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
}
form .range input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb, form .average input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: gray;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  cursor: -moz-grab;
  height: 20px;
  pointer-events: all;
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
}
form .range input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb:active, form .average input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb:active {
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
  cursor: -moz-grabbing;
}
form .range input[type="range"]#avgRange, form .average input[type="range"]#avgRange {
  margin: 1rem 0;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <span>
    <label for="minText">Min value</label>
    <input type="number" id="minText" value="0" onchange="equalizeMin(this.value)" min="0" />
  </span>
  <span>
    <label for="maxText">Max value</label>
    <input type="number" id="maxText" value="100" onchange="equalizeMax(this.value)" min="0" />
  </span>
  <div class="range">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="1000" value="0" id="minRange" onchange="equalizeMin(this.value)">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="1000" value="100" id="maxRange" onchange="equalizeMax(this.value)">
   </div>
  <br>
  <div class="average">
    <span>
      <label for="avgText">New value</label>
      <input type="number" id="avgText" value="50" onchange="equalizeAvg(this.value)" />
    </span>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="1000" value="50" id="avgRange" onchange="equalizeAvg(this.value)" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out!

It turned out that the value pulled from the range inputs was not a number. The fact that I had to change it to a number when calculating the average should have indicated it, but I missed it completely.

What happened was that a minimum value of 4 is thought of as bigger than 300.

Converting the values to a number with `Number(...)` solved my problem.